# How to set .data() variable inside an ASP script so it can be accessed later?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp-classic, callback, jquery-data

I am using `$.post()` to call an ASP script, which among other things has the following code:

```
%>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    strTributeID = <% NTC %>
    $('body').data(tributeID, strTributeID);
    alert ($('body').data(tributeID));
    </script>
<%
```

Before the page is refreshed (so DOM data should not have been wiped out), I call another $.post() which does this upon success:

```
var strTributeID = $('body').data(tributeID);
```

However, the value does not appear to be retained, or perhaps not set correctly. What might be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not writing the `NTC` value to the page, only evaluating it and throwing it away. Use the `<%=` tag:

```
strTributeID = <%= NTC %>;
```

Comment: This is classic ASP, so I don't believe that will work for me.

Comment: @Michael Hopkins: It's the same for classic ASP. `<% %>` is a code tag, and `<%= %>` is a display tag. `<%= %>` is short for `<%response.write( )%>`.